# How to run Brunch + React on local network

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy, httpserver, brunch

I want share my generated Brunch project on my local network so that I can see how it runs on my mobile devices.

I am trying to do this by running `http-server` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) in the public catalogue.

When I navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` I see nothing on the page but I do see the generated app.js file but it doesn't run.

How do I share the Brunch project on the local network?

Comment: Is your app running in your PC?

Comment: Yes, but is on my Mac :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, make sure both your computer and mobile is on the same network.
Then, you need to find the IP address of your machine by typing `ipconfig` in the terminal.
So for instance if your IP is `192.168.1.100`, then you may open the react app (given it is up and running on port 8080) in your phone by going to `192.168.1.100:8080` and not `http://127.0.0.1:8080` which is merely a loopback address